# Filling the data variables in arrays of objects

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, nullreferenceexception

```
class Customer
{
 public string name;
 public sting nic;
 public int age;

 public void add_customer()
    {
        // some code here to assign the values to the data types
    }
}

class main_menu
{
   Customer[] cust = new Customer[100];
   // some other data members

   public void new_customer()
   {
      // Some Console.WriteLine pritings
      cust[0].add_customer();
      // ------>> Now here in this line error is arrising which says
      An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in   Assignment 2.exe

      Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


   }
}
```

Now what i want to do is to Fill the data variables in arrays of objects one by one in all the customers instances

Kindly help me because i am beginner

Comment: You do not initialize `cust[0]`. try `cust[0] = new Customer()`

Comment: Thanks it worked.
But what is the purpose of using it because i want to understand the behind logic of this usage.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cust[0]` is null thus trying to access one of his properties or methods before assigning it a value will cause this exception.

**You main misunderstanding - by initializing cust you didn't initialized any one of the objects in it  ( cust[i] will be null for every i).**

You need to validate it before using it:

```
class main_menu
{
   Customer[] cust = new Customer[100];
   // some other data members

   public void new_customer()
   {
    cust[0] = new Customer();

      // when you want to use it later on, do this validation.
    if (cust[0] != null)
    {      
        cust[0].add_customer();
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you generate a collection to hold 100 customer objects, and then you are attempting to populate the fields of the first customer, but in the collection it does not exist yet. Idiomatically in C# we generate an empty collection, and then populate this collection with fully initialized Customer objects. Something like:

```
public class main_menu
{
  List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>(); // empty collection of Customer's
  public void new_customer(string name, string nickname, int age)
  {
    customers.Add( new Customer { name, nickname, age } );
  }
}
```

You should see two news, one for the collection, and one for each of the (reference) objects inserted into the collection.

Comment: Sir this information is new for me .. Thanks
But what if i want to hold unlimited customers instead of 100 ?

Comment: Then array isn't the data structure you will want to use - List is more suitable in this case.